# How can I query a MongoDB collection by both a geo spatial index and a text index quickly?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Given the collection `locations` consisting of ~20,000,000 documents with 3 properties:

```
{
    _id,
    name, // string
    geo // coordinate pair, e.g. [-90.123456, 30.123456]
}
```

and an index of `name: 1` and a geo index setup like so:

```
{ 
    "geo" : "2dsphere"
},
{ 
    "v" : 1, 
    "name" : "geo_2dsphere", 
    "ns" : "db.locations", 
    "min" : "-180.0", 
    "max" : "180.0", 
    "w" : 1.0, 
    "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
}
```

How can I performantly query against this collection both on the `geo_2dsphere` index and on the `name` index?

When I run a `$box` query on the geo index only, it takes over 20 seconds to return 50 results. When I include a search against the `name` property it goes up even further.

If I run a `$near` query, then things *can* perform very quickly, but sometimes queries seem to (very randomly) go from ~200ms to many seconds. See this example where the only difference is one additional character on the name index which actually increases the time:

200ms:

```
{name: /^mac/, geo: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ -90.123456, 30.123456 ]}, $maxDistance: 20000}}}
```

18,000ms:

```
 {name: /^macy/, geo: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ -90.123456, 30.123456 ]}, $maxDistance: 20000}}}
```

I can't understand why being more specific with an index is slowing things down so much. When I get more specific with a phrase, I have to drastically reduce the `$maxDistance` to something like 7,000 meters before the query returns in any reasonable amount of time.

Is there a better setup I should be doing here?

Comment: You cannot. There is a "higlander rule" ( there can be only one ) in the query evaluation that denies the usage of more than "one" "special" index in a query evaluation. So you cannot have multiple "text" or muliple "geospatial" or any combination of "text" and "geospatial" **or** usage of any oth those within an **`$or`** condition, that results in multiple index selection. As to your query time variations. "Too broad". You need to sample properly, and that means on a clean host with no other operations and "fully warmed" ( all results possible ) in memory.

Comment: Thanks Blakes. I realize my time examples are too broad and I don't mean for them to be taken concretely, just that there is obviously an undesired and varied difference in response time. I suppose we'll need to look into a different database entirely.

Comment: There is also a variant "catch" here, where the concept of a "search on name" may very well **not** be the thing that narrows down that data. For example: `.createIndex({ "name": 1, "geo": "2dphere" })` looks fine in  principle. But if there are "more" of "macy" than locations near the "geo" point, then this becomes counter productive. Indexing is a design of "data awareness", and not just the terms you use to query. Propellerheads have been vaunting this for yearrs in the SQL community. For the main reason that no others understand indexing concepts fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out to me by Blakes Seven, you cannot search across multiple indexes in MongoDB:

> There is a "highlander rule" (there can be only one) in the query
>   evaluation that denies the usage of more than "one" "special" index in
>   a query evaluation. So you cannot have multiple "text" or muliple
>   "geospatial" or any combination of "text" and "geospatial" or usage of
>   any of those within an $or condition, that results in multiple index
>   selection.

So, I've opted to move over to Elasticsearch for this specific query, indexing only what I need to complete these multi-index queries, and then use those results to load the necessary Mongo documents. Works quickly, works well.